# Compare 2 consecutive rows - create and populate column is criteria is met

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to compare consecutive rows and if the following criteria is met, I would like to create and populate a new column called Electronic_to_manual with a 'Y'

Here is my query

```
select distinct user_id, trans_id, status,date, source
from `table1`
where date >= '20171207'
order by user_id, trans_id, source asc, status desc
```

I basically want to look at all rows where source like '%manual%' and if souce = 'electronic' in the row immediately before for the same user_id and trans_id combo, I want to populate the electronic_to_manual field for that row with 'Y'

See example below.

```
user_id trans_id    Status  Date        Source          Electronic_to_manual (new column)   
123     1           Open    12/8/2017   Electronic  
123     1           Closed  12/8/2017   Electronic  
123     1           Closed  12/8/2017   Electronic  
123     1           Open    12/8/2017   Manual COB      Y    
123     1           Closed  12/9/2017   Manual COB  
456     1           Closed  12/8/2017   Manual COB  
456     23          Open    12/8/2017   Electronic  
456     23          Closed  12/8/2017   Manual Request  Y   
789     45          Open    12/8/2017   Electronic  
789     45          Closed  12/8/2017   Electronic  
789     45          Closed  12/8/2017   Electronic
```

Comment: Is there some other column that specifies the order these rows are in - there is no unique order column in the specified data.

Comment: The order is driven by order by clause in the query

Comment: `lag(source) over(partition by user_id , trans_id order by source asc, status desc)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LAG` function along these lines:

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN (LOWER(source) LIKE '%manual%'
                   AND LOWER(prev_source) LIKE '%electronic%')
            THEN 'Y'
            ELSE NULL END
       AS Electronic_to_manual

  FROM (SELECT *
              ,LAG(source) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                                 ORDER BY trans_id, source, status)
               AS prev_source
          FROM table1
          ORDER BY user_id
        ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

For the update requested:

```
update Table1
set electronic_to_manual = 'Y'
where exists (
      select 1
      from (
           select t.*
             , lag(t.source) over(partition by t.user_id , t.trans_id order by t.source asc, t.status desc) prev_source
           from table1 t
           ) d
      where source like 'Manual%' and prev_source = 'Electronic'
      and table1.user_id = d.user_id
            and table1.trans_id = d.trans_id
            and table1.transdate = d.transdate
            and table1.source = d.source
     )
```

*dbfiddle [Demo here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=59bd62ff471718091a6d3ec6b6b30b58)*

```
select d.*
from (
     select t.*
       , lag(source) over(partition by user_id , trans_id order by source asc, status desc) prev_source
     from table1 t
     ) d
where source like 'Manual%' and prev_source = 'Electronic'
order by user_id , trans_id, source asc, status desc
```

Comment: I don't have update rights. Can you simplify the query to be a select statement?

Comment: did you follow the link from the demo? it's all there already.

Comment: urious, why did you ask for an update? *I would like to create and populate a new column called Electronic_to_manual with a 'Y'*

Comment: I wanted to derive that column with a select statement. I didn't communicate it well, sorry!

Comment: "create and populate" made me believe you wanted to store it. oh well *c'est la vie*